# BeautifulSoup not properly parsing script text/template

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a fairly complex template script that BeautifulSoup4 isn't understanding for some reason. As you can see below, BS4 is only parsing partially into the tree before giving up. Why is this and is there a way to fix it?

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<script id="scriptname" type="text/template"><section class="sectionname"><header><h1>Test</h1></header><table><tr><th>Title</th><td class="class"></td><th>Title</th><td class="class"></td></tr><tr><th>Title</th><td class="class"></td><th>Another row</th><td class="checksum"></td></tr></table></section></script> Other stuff I want to stay"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.findAll('script')
[<script id="scriptname" type="text/template"><section class="sectionname"><header><h1>Test</script>]
```

Edit: on further testing, for some reason it appears that BS3 is able to parse this correctly:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs3
>>> soup = bs3(html)
>>> soup.script
<script id="scriptname" type="text/template"><section class="sectionname"><header><h1>Test</h1></header><table><tr><th>Title</th><td class="class"></td><th>Title</th><td class="class"></td></tr><tr><th>Title</th><td class="class"></td><th>Another row</th><td class="checksum"></td></tr></table></section></script>
```

Comment: which version of BS are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.3.2

Comment: find_all and findAll are the same. I get the same results regardless http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names

Comment: It's not finding the entire tag as I wrote it. It should be returning the whole script tag and not just part of it.

Comment: You sure that this is all information? In my local machine this code works perfect!

Comment: What is the findAll returning in your local machine? is it returning the whole script tag or just part of it?

Comment: @jumbopap [here's what i get](http://pastebin.com/xzT2mjnG)

Comment: @vikki I have no idea why I'm not getting that, either on my local machine or the server I'm working on. Is there any reason why BS4 would be unable to parse what I made?

Comment: `findAll` output is too big, but it return all between tag `script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautiful Soup sometimes fail with its default parser. Beautiful Soup supports the HTML parser included in Python’s standard library, but it also supports a number of third-party Python parsers.

In some cases I have to change the parser to other like : lxml, html5lib or any other.

This is a example of the explanation above :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
```

I recommend you read this http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: I will look into it; I have to install a dependency for this to work.

Comment: yes, you can install lxml directly using pip from your command line or download the package from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml‎>

Comment: I couldn't get lxml working for some reason but I got this working with the html5lib parser. Giving you the correct answer for the heads up :) Thanks.